# Did the Prophet advise against eating in excess on Eid?

Tags: sunnah, food, eid

You are permitted to cook and prepare nice, sumptuous special foods, but can you eat in excess?

Some non Muslims think that we do this to "compensate" for fasting in the month. Or is the advice of the Prophet (saws) to have one's stomach of 1/3 food, 1/3 water/liquid and 1/3 air still apply, or just eat moderately but not in excess?

Comment: Please try to elaborate your question to make clear what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

Eating in excess is always discouraged in Islam. There is no exception to this for Eid. See the following Quran verse and hadith.

> O children of Adam, take your adornment at every masjid, and **eat and
>   drink, but be not excessive.** Indeed, He likes not those who commit
>   excess. [Quran 7:31](https://quran.com/7/31)
>
> "I heard the Messenger of Allah (S.a.w) saying: 'The human does not
>   fill any container that is worse than his stomach. It is sufficient
>   for the son of Adam to eat what will support his back. If this is not
>   possible, then a third for food, a third for drink, and third for his
>   breath." https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/36/77